Formal/scientific word meaning to have horns
Need a one-word scientific/biology domain solution for this sentence (to express they all have horns):

Deer, ibex and bovine are all _______ animals.

So the Greek for horn is κέρας, and we have precedent for using Greek suffixes, namely that of Head" cephalos, so might we term it as keracephalos?
I searched that term and nothing came up though. On the other hand, I would be nothing short of shocked if there were truly no one-word solution for this concept -- especially since we are in the domain of biology which has such an endowed vocabulary, which to the Biology outsiders, has a seemingly unnecessary level of specificity, yet for Biologist's purposes, they must have it this way for their research.
Consider:

Polycephaly (multiple heads)
Parthenogenesis (virginal birth, hyperovulation)
Quadrupedal (four-legged)
Ect.

Surely a word "to have horns" would be less abstract and offer utility beyond many of the above examples.

The Latin root for 'horn' is cornu, so you might poke around for 'cornate', 'incornate' and similar.

Is "horned" not adequate ?

Seems like there is indeed a solution in Latin: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornigerous @JimMack. Good tip

Deer have antlers, not horns; they are not the same. Antlers are shed; true horns are not.

@HippoSawrUs Had no idea, will note for the future. Thanks

And there are several classifications for the different horn types; rather complicated. Good luck. Is there a zoology site?

https://biology.stackexchange.com/ would be the place for your zoology questions.

@JimMack I would think "cornate" would be for anything shaped like a horn.

Horny has the meaning 'having horns' also but yeah, it’s hard to horn in on that meaning without it causing confusion!

From biological point of view not all horns are equal, and many things that look like horns are not horns at all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_(anatomy)

Yes, the OP wants to allow horns and antlers but it would be strange to exclude ossicones (those things on giraffe heads) and at least some animals with purely keratin horns (rhino); but what about tusks, reptile and dinosaur horns, the various protrusions on insect heads, and many more things?

The word is horned, defined by Merriam-Webster as (among other things):

one of the usually paired bony processes that arise from the head of many ungulates and that are found in some extinct mammals and reptiles [...].

That's a fine word that conveys exactly what you mean. Yes, biologists, like other scientists and experts in various fields, do like their esoteric jargon, but even we aren't that desperate to show off that we would reject a perfectly decent word just to invent a new one.
There are dozens of species whose common name includes horned, and more than a thousand occurrences of the word horned in the scientific literature (a few random examples below):

A genome-wide association study (GWAS) was performed using 34 two-horned and 32 four-horned sheep from three Chinese indigenous breeds:

(source: Anim Genet. 2016 Oct;47(5):623-7. doi: 10.1111/age.12464.)

Within the Orthoptera, the family Acrididae contains about 6700 species of short-horned grasshoppers.

(source: J Chem Ecol. 2022 Feb;48(2):121-140. doi: 10.1007/s10886-021-01333-3.)

In this article, we review and summarize recent progress in the development of horned beetles and beetle horns

(source: Wiley Interdiscip Rev Dev Biol. 2013 May-Jun;2(3):405-18. doi: 10.1002/wdev.81.
So don't reinvent the wheel, use horned, that's what it's for.

Deer, ibex and bovines are all horned animals.


Deer do not have horns. They have antlers. This is a serious error for the formal/biology term requested. See also HippoSawrUs's comment below the question.

You're quire right, of course, @PhilSweet, however since one of the meanings of horn is actually antler (see meaning 1a(2) in M-W), unless one is trying to make the distinction or referring to deer specifically, I would argue it is still a valid use of horned.

If we insist on using Greek: κεράσφορος, which we might be content in rendering as "kerasphoric". However, the term has no real precedent.
Latin would give us: cornigerous, which does have some mainstream recognition.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornigerous
Thanks for all interested and those offering suggestions

I’m with @Criggie and would encourage you to strongly consider horned. Simpler is very often better.

That would be kerasphorous not kerasphoric though. But please explain what is wrong with horned.

@terdon There are a myriad of scientific papers that rely on Latin and Greek terms that are mostly unintelligible to the average lay person. If the OP is writing for scholars and zoologists, the answer "cornigerous” is also appropriate.

@Mari-LouA it may be, although as a biologist myself, I hadn't come across it before, and I find not a single usage  of the word in the biological literature (PubMed link; which I freely admit is really weird, at least some of your GScholar results seem to be from peer reviewed biological papers). So I am not entirely convinced of its usefulness. In any case, my comment was about kerasphoric vs kerasphorous and the very commonly used, even in scientific contexts, horned. So I am not sure what point you're trying to make.

I apologise if my point was unclear.  You asked to explain what was wrong with "horned". I addressed that specific point, the term which you also appear to strongly support in your answer. The OP asked for a formal/scientific word. Can you say "horned" is particularly scientific, more so than cornigerous, a word that I had never heard of either? But "corna" is Italian for horn so it would be an easy adjective for me to remember, there's also the mythical creature unicorn.

Scientific is as scientific does. The word horned is clearly very widely used in scientific context, so I don't see why we would go for anything else. Even in Google Scholar, we get 52 hits for cornigerous (many of which don't seem to be real, actually, or at least I don't see the word in the linked document), and more than 200 thousand for horned.  And in PubMed, 0 for the former.

@MariLouA  The question now is whether it is "a formal scientific word" or "a formal-sounding scientific-sounding word".

@Mari-LouA Please note that in the sources shown in your link, "cornigerous" is used to describe flowers rather than animals.

Plenty of cornigerous animals in Google Books

@Mari-LouA but very few if you change the selection to 20th C onwards. Which I think is relevant to how the term would be understood by present day biologists (of which I am one)

"If we insist on using Greek" Why would we insist on using Greek? Are you asking for a well-known and well-defined term or an obscure creation you think will make you sound smarter?

I would not render κεράσφορος as kerasphorous (even less kerasphoric). The normal combining form of the Greek word κέρας ‘horn’ when used in English words – also found in Greek, even for this particular word – is kerato-, so I would render it as keratophorous. That would be recognisable and parseable if you know what keratin is and what -phorous as a suffix means (both of which can be found in any dictionary). Kerasphorous requires knowing the actual Greek word to make sense. (Compare opaque phosphorous with transparent photophorous.)

Ah, thanks, @JanusBahsJacquet. That feels much more natural to me but as a Greek speaker, I feared I was getting confused by the fact that kerato is the modern Greek term for horn.

@terdon This is an example showing that Classical Greek was in flux: the origin of the combining -o- in Greek (and Latin) compounds is the ‘theme’ vowel that characterised some noun stems (‘thematic nouns’) and thus the accusative case, which is the most common when the first element in a compound is the object of the second (verb-derived). Κέρας is neuter and athematic in CG, so its accusative was κέρας, and the original form is thus κεράσφορος; but already in CG, the ‘pull’ of combining forms in -o- was strong enough that κερατόφορος had been created analogically and was also found.

@Mari-LouA "Can you say "horned" is particularly scientific..." We use fancy jargon a lot in scientific literature, but that's because the colloquial terms are often a bit too ambiguous and we need to be precise. We don't shouldn't use jargon just to sound fancy. Good scientific writing is precise and clear.

I'm surprised that no one has brought up cornute. I think it has a nice ring to it.

Deer, ibex and bovine are all cornute animals.

The word is from Latin cornūtus ("horned, having horns"). Here's an example of use from an 1898 book:

This is further illustrated by the action of the two domestic cornute animals, butting and rebutting one another.

The term has also been used in reference to cuckolds, who were associated with "having horns", although I doubt anyone would be making that connection today.
Further reading:

https://www.oed.com/dictionary/cornute_adj
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornute


Speakers of various Latin languages are very likely to make the cuckold connection, actually. The Spanish word for it is cornudo, the Italian cornuto, corno in Portuguese and so on. Granted, there's no reason an English speaker would make the connection, but the polyglots might.

There is nothing wrong with the term horned, it is understandable to all anglophone speakers. However, the OP is looking for a scientific and formal term; someone in the comments suggested cornigerous, certainly it is an obscure word but there are numerous instances of it in Google books, when taxonomic names inspired by Latin and Greek were held in higher esteem than today.
The meaning of unicorn is easily understood, so I asked myself whether bicorn existed, meaning a creature with two horns. There is the bicorn(e) hat, famously worn by Napoleon, and soon after I unearthed bicornis. For example, the south-western black rhinoceros's Latin name is Diceros bicornis occidentalis and the great hornbill, which has two horn-like protrusions on its beak, is scientifically called Buceros bicornis.


The great hornbill was formally described by the Swedish naturalist Carl Linnaeus in 1758 in the tenth edition of his Systema Naturae. He placed it with the rhinoceros hornbill in the genus Buceros and coined the binomial name Buceros bicornis. The genus name is from Latin becerus meaning "horned like an ox" which in turn is from the Ancient Greek boukerōs which combines bous meaning "ox" with kerōs meaning "horn". The specific bicornis is Latin and means "two-horned".
Wikipedia


And the "tricorne" or "tricorn" is a hat.

Coming from the German point of view: We have the word "Stirnwaffenträger", which means something like "bearer of a forehead weapon" or "forehead weapon carrier". This term consolidates all animals, which have antlers, horns, boney protrusions, etc. Everything that is on a forehead and can be used as a weapon mostly.
The English Wikipedia article for Stirnwaffenträger is Pecora.

But what about rhinoceroses?

Good catch! They indeed don't carry a weapon on their forehead. This may disqualify my answer. And unfortunately we don't use the word "Nasenwaffenträger" (Nose weapon carrier).

There isn't one suitable for a formal discussion.
bovine horns are different from deer antlers are different from giraffe horns are different from rhino horns are different from  pronghorn horns.

Some folks just don't appreciate irony, I guess.

… and horned owl horns.

Semi-related, but there's of course the suffix cera:
-cera
noun combining form
sərə
plural-cera
: horned one : horned ones —in taxonomic names in zoology
Acrocera
Cladocera
Nematocera


Ceratopsians are dinosaurs.
